# StreamReader ReadLine loop freezing program

Tags: c#

I'm writing a basic client and server program using Tcp sockets and stream readers/writers. My client and server connect fine and can send single line messages using StreamWriter and StreamReader.ReadLine(); However when i wish to read multiple lines, my loop freezes and never continues to the rest of the code.

Client:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(hostname, port);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());

sw.WriteLine("PUT /" + name + "\r\n" + "nextline" + "\r\n" + "moreline" + "\r\n");
sw.Flush();               //eventually used for http style request
Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

Server:

```
static void runServer()
    {
        TcpListener listener;
        Socket connection;
        NetworkStream socketStream;

        try
        {
            listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 43);
            listener.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Server Listening...");

            while (true)
            {
                connection = listener.AcceptSocket();
                socketStream = new NetworkStream(connection);
                Console.WriteLine("Connection Received...");
                doRequest(socketStream);
                socketStream.Close();
                connection.Close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

static void doRequest(NetworkStream socketStream)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(socketStream);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(socketStream);

            String line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }

            sw.WriteLine("Success");
            sw.Flush();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

    }
```

Output:

```
Server Listening...
Connection Recieved...
PUT /dave
nextline
moreline
```

However the program does not do the sw.WriteLine("Success"), sw.Flush(), or any Console.WriteLine() either.
Any other method I have tried only reads in the first line, and then the client recieves the "Success Message" and the server continues as it should.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Just to clarify, I only wish to send this one WriteLine() from my client to the server, however I wish to split up the lines so I can send back the correct data from my server to the client.

Comment: It seems like you need to indicate that the stream is done on the client side.  What if you close `sw` instead of flushing it?

Comment: You are closing the connection so only one message is received and you have a potential race condition when you send message and then immediately close the connection so the send message may never get received.

Comment: @juharr i tried changing sw to .close() on the client and the server. but the same issue occured